# C - memset segfault for statically allocated char array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memset

I get a segfault when trying to `memset` an array of chars that was allocated statically, but not for an array of the same length that was allocated using `malloc`.

variable definitions:

```
    //static
    char inBuff[IN_BUFF_LEN];
    //dynamic
    char * inBuffD;
```

function call:

```
    //static, cast used because char** != char (*) [n]
    serverInit(portNum, (char**) &inBuff, &serv_addr, &sockfd)
    //dynamic
    serverInit(portNum, &inBuffD, &serv_addr, &sockfd)
```

use within the function:

```
    memset(*inBuffAdr, 0, IN_BUFF_LEN);
```

I suspect that my problem is in the difference of the function calls, or to be more precise, my incomplete understanding of the "char** != char (*) [n]" situation. But I have been banging at this for too long and can't see the forest from the trees so any hints and advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: What is `inBuffAdr` and how is it set?

Comment: it is just some structure which is used elsewhere and is unimportant for the question at hand. but if you really want to know i can give you some details

Answer (score 4):

Just send inBuff (not **inBuff) and then memset inBuffAdr and not *inBufAdr (your other memset is probably not working either, you just don't know it yet)

Comment: +1 for the "not working either, but you just don't know it yet".

Comment: I was trying to have the pointer variable outside the function but be able to set its value if needed, thus the double pointer. As for the other memset it seems to be working for now, but I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to pass a double-pointer to your `serverInit()` function?  If the function can modify where the pointer points to, then you can't pass a statically allocated array.  If the function can't modify where the pointer points to, then you don't need a double-pointer.

The type of `&inBuff` is pointer to array of `char` of size `IN_BUFF_LEN`, which is quite distinct from a `char **`.  You've bludgeoned the compiler into not complaining, claiming that you know better than the compiler what you're doing.   Don't use a cast like that unless you are sure you do know more than the compiler.

Frankly, given the current prototype, you'd probably be best off with:

```
//static
char inBuff[IN_BUFF_LEN];
char *inBuffS = inBuff;
//dynamic
char *inBuffD;

serverInit(portNum, &inBuffS, &serv_addr, &sockfd);
```

However, I'm deeply suspicious that you should revise `serverInit()` to take a simple `char *` instead of `char **` for the second argument.

Comment: Started to say that `char**` is probably wrong in a comment but you beat me too it.  I would also add that it's often good practice to carry array size info around with an array unless your are quite certain you will never want to change its size.  In other words change the prototype to `serverInit( short port, char * buf, size_t bufsize, struct sockaddr * addr, int * fd )`.  And actually, I question the need for the fd being a pointer.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: I agree with what you say.  If the `serverInit()` function is opening the `fd` and returning it to the calling code, then the pointer is more or less justified.  However, if you've got multiple return parameters like that, it is probably worth putting them all into a structure, and the function simply takes a pointer to the structure and fills in the details as appropriate.  One problem with the question is that we have barely enough context to be able to make any answer that's helpful.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment the double pointer is because I want to be able to change the value of the pointer from within the function so passing the value wouldn't cut it.

@JonathanLeffler Those are multiple return values. I will put them into a structure but this is basically just a mock up of the final function. First i want to make it work and later i'll wrap it up. As for the context, i'm afraid there isn't much more code around the one I posted, at least none that interacts with the inBuffAdr value

Answer (score 0):

Why not define `serverInit()` the following way:

```
serverInit(...., char * inBuff, ....)
```

then call it

```
serverInit(...., inBuff, ....)
```

and then inside `serverInit()` call `memset()` like this:

```
memset(inBuff, 0, IN_BUFF_LEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of your confusion is in thinking that `&inBuff` can be dereferenced to get `inBuff`.  If you run this simple test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char inBuff[1000];
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf( "%p %p\n", inBuff, &inBuff);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll see that it prints the same address for both notations.  If you try to dereference `&inBuff`, you'll be taking the first few bytes of the array as an address.

As others have stated, you should just be passing a pointer to the memory you're going to set.  Hopefully this answer will help you with future debugging sessions.